# How to Validate keycloak token in node js using keycloak version 20.0.2

Tags: node.js, keycloak

This is my middleware code. I want to validate access token in this middleware. But I am getting error. I tried a lot of ways, but I cannot get the result. please help me to solve this.

```
    const validateTokenMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  const realm = 'my-realm';
  const introspectUrl = `${process.env.KC_BASE_URL}/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect`;
  console.log('introspectUrl', introspectUrl);
  const data = new URLSearchParams();
  data.append('token', token);
  data.append('client_id', 'admin-cli');
  data.append('client_secret', 'my-client-secret');
  console.log('data', data);
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(introspectUrl, data, config);
    if (response.data.active) {
      req.user = response.data;
      next();
    } else {
      throw new Error('Token is not active');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    // console.error(`Error validating token: ${error}`);
    res.sendStatus(401);
  }
};



app.use(validateTokenMiddleware)
```

I am getting the below error.
data: {
error: 'invalid_request',
error_description: 'Client not allowed.'
}

In keycloak server console  displayed like this.
2023-05-11 09:27:45,492 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-0) type=INTROSPECT_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=4b9e9f13-f5i8-473e-jd59-7093c8b711fa, clientId=admin-cli, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_request, detail='Client not allowed.', client_auth_method=client-secret.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What error message do you get? Please edit your question and add the error message.

Comment: @Geshode  I add error description and changed the code also.